# Git clone error: cannot exec '/myrepo/.git/hooks/post-checkout': Permission denied

Tags: git, git-clone, git-lfs

I have a git repo on which I have enabled lfs (large file storage) by running following command:

```
git lfs track "*.pickle"
```

I commited this repo and cloned it on another machine. But it gave me following error:

```
# git clone https://github.com/myuserid/myrepo.git
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 54, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (17/17), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 54 (delta 4), reused 15 (delta 3), pack-reused 37
Unpacking objects: 100% (54/54), 59.20 MiB | 7.40 MiB/s, done.
Updating files: 100% (34/34), done.
Filtering content: 100% (14/14), 133.40 MiB | 34.05 MiB/s, done.
fatal: cannot exec '/myrepo/.git/hooks/post-checkout': Permission denied
```

How to fix this?
Also, the files seem to have checked out on my disk. So, is it just fine to continue ignoring the error messages? Also if it is due to lfs, I am ok to revert this back, that is get rid of lfs. But how do I do this?

PS: This never happened with me earlier with non lfs repos. This is the first time I am using lfs and thats why I am guessing its lfs that is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

`fatal: cannot exec '/myrepo/.git/hooks/post-checkout': Permission denied` means more or less what it says: Git was unable to run the post-checkout hook for permissions reasons. It could be something with the way the LFS extension is implemented on your system - [git-lfs adds a post-checkout hook](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/git-lfs-post-checkout.1.html) to manage things like file locks - but we'd need further details to troubleshoot more specifically.

The good news, though, is that the post-checkout hook only runs after the **successful** completion of a checkout. (`git clone` does a checkout at the end of the process, unless you specified `--bare` or `--mirror`; that's how it populates the working directory with the contents at the default branch's HEAD.) You have all the files, you just didn't get whatever cleanup tasks were meant to be done in the post-checkout script.

Once you've sorted out the post-checkout script permissions, then you should be able to get the appropriate repo state by running `git checkout` on the default branch (usually either `main` or `master`).

Comment: Sorry, but didnt get what you suggest. You want me to run `chmod 777` on  the file?

Comment: Probably better to long-list the file in question (`ls -l`) and see what its current ownership and permissions are first, and then `chown` or `chmod 755` if necessary. You should also check that your user is allowed to execute `git-lfs`.

The permissions issue may also be in a file the script was attempting to manage, though. If everything looks good on the script permissions, you could potentially change the hook to be more verbose in its output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## git lfs clone https://github.com/myuserid/myrepo.git

"lfs" would solve the issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34643240)